# Should scandir() be recognized in the dirent.h of minGW-W64?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw-w64

When I try to compile using GCC (minGW-W64) with the `dirent.h` header file, `scandir` is not recognized as a function. Should it be? I'm trying to run the GNU GCC example code for scandir.

I'm uncertain about which is the latest version also. Some posts state GCC 10 or 10.1 but aren't clear about the minGW-W64 version. `GCC -- version` produces:

`gcc (x86_64-posiz-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0.`

Is this the most recent version?

Everything else I've used thus far appears to work fine. I was able to compile my code with the SQLite3 amalgamation file with no issues and execute SQL. Also, `readdir` is recognized, compiles, and excecutes as expected.

This is the sample code. `alphasort` is not recognized either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>


static int
one (const struct dirent *unused)
{
  return 1;
}

int
main (void)
{
  struct dirent **eps;
  int n;

  n = scandir ("./", &eps, one, alphasort);
  if (n >= 0)
    {
      int cnt;
      for (cnt = 0; cnt < n; ++cnt)
        puts (eps[cnt]->d_name);
    }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read `Feature Test Macro Requirements` and `man feature_test_macros`?

Comment: No. From where?

Comment: [man feature_test_macros](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)  and [man scandir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html). From [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) - the best documentation. Also it could be that minGW (or what you have there) just doesn't implement the function.

Comment: Thanks. I thought you were referring to documentation of minGW-W64. I'll look this over and see if it is the issue.

Comment: That's for glibc on Linux. Probably not applicable to mingw.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, I changed it to _GNU_SOURCE which appears to be the most inclusive setting and `scandir` is still not recognized. I can accomplish what I need with `readdir`, which is recognized; so, likely isn't worth wasting hours over to find out it just isn't currently supported.

Comment: I doubt it means much, but sometimes I check the IBM Knowledege Center and `scandir` isn't even listed there as a function.

Comment: `MinGW` is for windows, `scandir()` I believe is `GNU C` library.  Not sure if the two intersect.

Comment: The closest Windows function(s) seems to be [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea), `FindNextFile()` and friends.

Comment: If I stopped using minGW and used a linux OS, can the GNU GCC compiler generate an executable file that will run in Windows? I don't have to build the code in Windows, but want the final executable to run in Windows and Linux, maybe Mac. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking about a cross compiler.  You can set this up, but it won't help.  When cross-compiling, you're still using the target's existing standard library, so you won't gain access to more functions just because you compile on a different machine.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh, so you mean that the difference between minGW and GNU GCC libraries is due to the fact that some of the functions just won't work in the Windows OS period?  I'm stupid, didn't realize that. Thank you.